# Finding a path with the biggest number of nodes in a directed graph

Tags: algorithm, graph

What would be a good way to find in a directed graph a path which has the biggest number of nodes?

I suppose I could traverse the graph in depth for each node and find out which path has the biggest number of nodes however I'm wondering if there are better approaches.

Mention: the graph is guaranteed to have no cycles.

Comment: You mean you want an algorithm to solve the [longest path problem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem)?

Comment: Your graph is a tree. Well almost... :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a directed acyclic graph(DAG) and you want to find the path with biggest number of nodes. This, is infact finding the `longest path` in DAG.

This problem is solvable for DAG in polynomial time. Read more about it here :- [Wikipedia.](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Longest_path_problem)

Comment: Thanks for the hint. I ended up solving it by using Floyd-Warshall's algorithm where each edge had a weight of -1.

Answer (score 2):

If graph has a cycle then there is "infinite" length path.

If graph is acyclic:
You should run topological sort. Then:

```
foreach(node in topological_sort_order) {
   foreach(prev_node in neibhours[node]) {
      // there is edge from prev_node to node
      // since vertices are sorted in topological order than
      // value for longest_path[prev_node] is already computed
      longest_path[node] = max(longest_path[node],  longest_path[prev_node] + 1);
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Since your input is a Directed Graph and not Directed Acyclic Graph then it is NP-Complete and the solutions mentioned do not work. But as logic_max said: it is the longest path problem, and you reduce that by giving each edge a cost one.